# Core(JS) - How to pass context from a forward navigation to a tabview?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I´m trying to pass context (peripheral) from a previous page to a tabView page, where all of tabviewItems need to use that information.

previousPage.js

```
      var navigationEntry = {
            moduleName: "tab-view/tab-view",
            context: {
                peripheral: peri
            },
            animated: true
        };
        var topmost = frameModule.topmost();
        topmost.navigate(navigationEntry);
    }
```

tab-view.js

```
function onNavigatedTo(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = page.navigationContext.peripheral;

}
```

tab-view.xml

```
    <Page actionBarHidden="true" navigatedTo="onNavigatedTo" loaded="onPageLoaded">
<TabView id="tabViewContainer" selectedIndex="0" androidTabsPosition="bottom">
    <TabViewItem title="Fan" ios:iconSource="res://tabIcons/circle" android:iconSource="res://search">
        <Frame defaultPage="fan/fan-page"></Frame>
    </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem title="HvT" ios:iconSource="res://tabIcons/circle" android:iconSource="res://search">
        <Frame defaultPage="hvt/hvt-page"></Frame>
    </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem title="Usage" ios:iconSource="res://tabIcons/circle" android:iconSource="res://search">
        <Frame defaultPage="usage/usage-page"></Frame>
    </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem title="Settings" ios:iconSource="res://tabIcons/circle" android:iconSource="res://search">
        <Frame defaultPage="settings/settings-page"></Frame>
    </TabViewItem>
</TabView>
```

From this point, what can I do to my tabViewItems get access to peripheral? I´m kinda new to nativescript and didn´t find a solution to this. I hope you can help me out. thanks

Comment: You can access any [ancestor's bindingContext](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#binding-to-a-parent-binding-context) using `$parents['CompName']`, so you might able to access TabViewItem's binding context, which has access to peripheral from a Page inside the TabViewItem.

Comment: That peripheral context is from a page outside tabview. I just need to be able to store that peripheral on a variable on each frame of  tabView to make bluetooth calls and not for UI structuring.

Answer (score 0):

You can access any [ancestor's bindingContext](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#binding-to-a-parent-binding-context) of a View using `$parents['CompName']`.

```
 <Label text="{{ $parents['Frame'].peripheral.propertyName }}" class="h2"></Label>
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=23yX49)

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to use that context on a xml. Peripheral is basically an object that has all the information that I need to communicate through bluetooth like this: `ble.write({
        peripheralUUID: peripheral.UUID,
        serviceUUID: 'd8b5ac12-17c5-11e8-b642-0ed5f89f718b',
        characteristicUUID: 'd8b5affa-17c5-11e8-b642-0ed5f89f718b',
        value: '0x' + flowRateValueHexa

    }).then(function (result) {

        console.log("FLOW RATE!");

    }, function (err) {
        console.log("write error: " + err);
    });
`